# primefaces validation message not showing (composite component, primefaces and validation method )

Tags: validation, jsf-2

This is peticionario, a composite component that asks you for your pin. It's not mandatory but if you fill in something it must be numeric and the app will look in the db so no other person has the same number:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:dabit="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">

<cc:interface> 
    <cc:attribute name="peticionarioB" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

<h:form id="peticionario_form">
<p:panel id="unooo">                
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="ohruiseñor">
    <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Datos personales"/>
        </f:facet>                  

        <h:outputText value="Número de documento"/>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:inputText 
        id="numDoc"
    validator="#{radicadoOficioBean.validarPeticionario}"
    value="#{peticionarioBean.peticionario.numDocumento}">
        <f:validateLongRange/>
    </h:inputText> 
    <h:message for="peticionario_form:numDoc" style="color:red"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>                            
</h:form>
```

This is _crear.xhtml, a page that uses peticionario component in a p:dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:dabit="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">

<h:body>    

<h:form id="form">
<p:panel header="Radicación de oficio" >
<p:dialog 
header="Creación de peticionario"
id="peticionario_dialog"    
widgetVar="peticionario_dlg">
    <dabit:peticionario peticionarioB="#{radicadoOficioBean.peticionarioBean}"/>    
        <p:ajax 
    event="close"  
    update="form:peticionarioExistentePG"/>  
</p:dialog>   
</h:body>
</html>
```

And this is RadicadoOficioBean's validate method

```
public void validarPeticionario (FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
if (value == null) {
    return;
}

Long l = new Long(value.toString());

if (DAOBase.findByUniqueLongProperty(Peticionario.class, "numDocumento", l) != null) {
    FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("ya existe un usuario con el numero de documento ingresado");
context.addMessage(component.getClientId(), fm);
fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
System.out.println(component.getClientId());
throw new ValidatorException(fm);
}       
}
```

The validation actually occurs :) but the message i cannot get :(

Comment: how about `for="numDoc"` instead of `for="peticionario_form:numDoc"` in the `h:message` ?

Comment: been there, done that. no joy :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h:inputText id="numDoc" ... /> 
<h:message for="peticionario_form:numDoc" ... />
```

This doesn't match. You should be using

```
<h:inputText id="numDoc" ... /> 
<h:message for="numDoc" ... />
```

Another possible cause, not visible in the code posted so far, is that you're sending an ajax request but not re-rendering the message component at all. You should make sure that you're re-rendering (updating) the message component or at least one of its parents on ajax request.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the way how you prepare the validation message is clumsy. It's unnecessary to manually add the message to the context. That job is already done when the `ValidatorException` is caught by JSF.

```
FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("ya existe un usuario con el numero de documento ingresado");
context.addMessage(component.getClientId(), fm);
fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
System.out.println(component.getClientId());
throw new ValidatorException(fm);
```

Just the following oneliner was been sufficient:

```
throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(
    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ya existe un usuario con el numero de documento ingresado", null);
```

Comment: mil gracias, funcionó. (mil = one thousand, gracias = thanks, funcionó = it worked)